# Почему программа крашится?? Язык С

Tags: c

Я не знаю почему крашится моя программа но в отладчике я прошёлся по программе и увидел что крашит её на строке где есть strcpy().Код как и само задание взято с Codewars. Вот ссылка:https://www.codewars.com/kata/58f5c63f1e26ecda7e000029

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void wave(const char *y, char **target) {
    int count=0,counts=0;
    const char *p = y;
    while(*y!='\0') {
  if(!isspace(*y)) {
      strcpy(target[count],p);
      target[count][counts]=toupper(*y);
      count++;
  }
  counts++,y++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const char* y = "Hello";
    char* target[] = {"Hello","Hello","Hello","Hello","Hello"};
    wave(y,target);
}
```

Вот исправленная версия но она всё равно крашится

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
void wave(const char *y, char **target) {
    int count=0,counts=0;
    const char *p = y;
    while(*y!='\0') {
  if(!isspace(*y)) {
      strcpy(target[count],p);
      target[count][counts]=toupper(target[count][counts]);
      count++;
  }
  counts++,y++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const char* y = "Hello";
    char* r = (char*)malloc((strlen(y)+1)*sizeof(char));
    wave(y,&r);
}
```

Comment: Я хотел узнать как работает программа но она не запускается. Смысл задания в том что тебе дается строка и ты должен превратить каждую букву в верхний регистр и записать эту новую строку в двумерный массив target.

Comment: У вас условие — *превратить каждую букву в верхний регистр и записать эту новую строку в двумерный массив `target`*, но `target` у вас на самом деле одномерный массив указателей. Имело бы смысл что-то вроде `char target[][10] = {"Hello","Hello","Hello","Hello","Hello"};` с соответствующей заменой типа аргумента в функции `wave`.

Comment: *"в отладчике я прошёлся по программе"* и *"она не запускается"* противоречат друг другу

Comment: Я прошёлся отладчиком из Code Blocks от начала программы и она крашнулась как только я дошёл до strcpy()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Инициализация через строку у кавычках даёт нам указатель на константу (`const char *`). На i386-совместимых платформах (возможно и на других) строка выделяется в области памяти, физически защищённой от записи. А вы пытаетесь её менять, вот и источник ошибки.

Comment: "Физически защищенной от записи" это значит её даже скопировать нельзя?? Получается ошибка в main??

Comment: @Narkoman123 саму константную строку скопировать можно, нельзя скопировать в константную строку.

Comment: указатели `target[i],y` указывают на одно и то-же место в скомпилированной программе. Менять код проги вы не можете. Разрешается создать **новую** строку и с ней работать дальше.